# Calling only once two functions in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I try to call two functions in my useEffect hook

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const LocalWeather = () => {
  const APP_KEY = "XXX";
  const [userPlace, setUserPlace] = useState([]);
  const [localWeather, setLocalWeather] = useState([]);

  async function getUserData() {
    await fetch("http://ip-api.com/json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUserPlace({
          country: data.country,
          city: data.city,
        });
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  async function getLocalWeather() {
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userPlace.city}&appid=${APP_KEY}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLocalWeather({
          temperature: Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15),
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getLocalWeather();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        Your current place is: {userPlace.country}, {userPlace.city}
      </h3>
      {localWeather.temperature ? (
        <h4>Temperature in your city is: {localWeather.temperature} &#8451;</h4>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I try to add [] to my use useEffect eslint automatically changes it into:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getLocalWeather();
  }, [getLocalWeather]);
```

What should I do to be able to call my both functions only on the first render?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can define `useEffect` with an empty dependency which will ensure that the functions only run once

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getLocalWeather();
  }, []);
```

However when you write it like above, eslint will complain regarding dependency. So either you can disable the warning like

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getLocalWeather();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Read more about it on this post: [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Or else if the function getUserData and getLocalWeather are mean to only be used inside the useEffect then you can declare them within useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
        await fetch("http://ip-api.com/json")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setUserPlace({
              country: data.country,
              city: data.city,
            });
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }

      async function getLocalWeather() {
        await fetch(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userPlace.city}&appid=${APP_KEY}`
        )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setLocalWeather({
              temperature: Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15),
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }

      getUserData();
      getLocalWeather();
  }, []);
```

However if for some reason you want to use them outside of `useEffect` too and also don't want to disable the warning, you can make use of `useCallback` for the functions and add them as a dependency

```js
 const getUserData = useCallback(async function() {
  await fetch("http://ip-api.com/json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setUserPlace({
        country: data.country,
        city: data.city,
      });
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);

const getLocalWeather = useCallback(async function getLocalWeather() {
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userPlace.city}&appid=${APP_KEY}`
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setLocalWeather({
        temperature: Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15),
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);


useEffect(() => {     
  getUserData();
  getLocalWeather();
}, [getUserData, getLocalWeather]);
```

Comment: @Treycos, Well there is a third solution too. Depends on the usecase :-)

Comment: The third approach is used when we want to do API calls in different events like fetch on load, fetch after some user input, fetch for page change, etc